# How to Debug blackberry app in Emulator and device

Tags: debugging, blackberry

How the device and emulator debugging is done in Eclipse for Blackberry development.

Comment: Well, for one thing the emulator only works in Windows. FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A50_How_to_Debug_and_Optimize_V2.pdf) and more [here](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/tutorials.jsp#tab_tab_development)

Comment: You should write something about the link.